# There "was" or there "were"

Tags: word-choice

Which of the following is correct and why:

1 - There were 2,223 people aboard RMS Titanic

2 - There was 2,223 people aboard RMS Titanic

Answer (score 2):

1- "There WERE plural people," because you say "plural people WERE there."

Otherwise, "There WAS one person," because you say "one person WAS there."

Answer (score 0):

There has always been this misunderstanding in the minds of people when they are constructing a sentence whether to use was or were in a particular sentence.
Now, the answer to it is pretty simple and you have to keep this small thing in your mind that-

"In a particular sentence, what are you referring to?"

If you are referring to a singular entity then you have to use **was** in it, but if you are referring to multiple/ plural entities then you have to use **were** in it.

Let's take an example which will help you to understand more clearly:

Q.) How many people attended the meeting?

Ans 1: It was just Sam who was present at the meeting.
(In this sentence, sam is a single entity so we use **was**.)

Ans 2: There were all the team members who attended the meeting.
(In this sentence, all team members are plural entity so we use **was**.)